# How can I draw a circle over a seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

Given I have a dataframe with x,y coordinates and a value, I am able to draw a heatmap via seaborn.
In a next step, I want to draw an addition circle within this data from the center of the plot with a radius of 10. Therefore I calculated x_center and y_center. Now I need to know how I can draw a circle within a heatmap, but I have no idea how to do that. Can you give me any idea?

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame( {'x': {1330: 13, 1331: 13, 1332: 13, 1333: 13, 1334: 13, 1335: 13, 1336: 13, 1429: 14, 1430: 14, 1431: 14, 1432: 14, 1433: 14, 1434: 14, 1435: 14, 1436: 14, 1437: 14, 1438: 14, 1439: 14, 1529: 15, 1530: 15, 1531: 15, 1532: 15, 1533: 15, 1534: 15, 1535: 15, 1536: 15, 1537: 15, 1538: 15, 1539: 15, 1540: 15, 1541: 15, 1629: 16, 1630: 16, 1631: 16, 1632: 16, 1633: 16, 1634: 16, 1635: 16, 1636: 16, 1637: 16, 1638: 16, 1639: 16, 1640: 16, 1641: 16, 1642: 16, 1643: 16, 1729: 17, 1730: 17, 1731: 17, 1732: 17, 1733: 17, 1734: 17, 1735: 17, 1736: 17, 1737: 17, 1738: 17, 1739: 17, 1740: 17, 1741: 17, 1742: 17, 1743: 17, 1744: 17, 1745: 17, 1829: 18, 1830: 18, 1831: 18, 1832: 18, 1833: 18, 1834: 18, 1835: 18, 1836: 18, 1837: 18, 1838: 18, 1839: 18, 1840: 18, 1841: 18, 1842: 18, 1843: 18, 1844: 18, 1845: 18, 1846: 18, 1847: 18, 1929: 19, 1930: 19, 1931: 19, 1932: 19, 1933: 19, 1934: 19, 1935: 19, 1936: 19, 1937: 19, 1938: 19, 1939: 19, 1940: 19, 1941: 19, 1942: 19, 1943: 19, 1944: 19, 1945: 19, 1946: 19, 1947: 19, 1948: 19, 1949: 19, 2030: 20, 2031: 20, 2032: 20, 2033: 20, 2034: 20, 2035: 20, 2036: 20, 2037: 20, 2038: 20, 2039: 20, 2040: 20, 2041: 20, 2042: 20, 2043: 20, 2044: 20, 2045: 20, 2046: 20, 2047: 20, 2048: 20, 2049: 20, 2050: 20, 2130: 21, 2131: 21, 2132: 21, 2133: 21, 2134: 21, 2135: 21, 2136: 21, 2137: 21, 2138: 21, 2139: 21, 2140: 21, 2141: 21, 2142: 21, 2143: 21, 2144: 21, 2145: 21, 2146: 21, 2147: 21, 2148: 21, 2149: 21, 2150: 21, 2151: 21, 2152: 21, 2231: 22, 2232: 22, 2233: 22, 2234: 22, 2235: 22, 2236: 22, 2237: 22, 2238: 22, 2239: 22, 2240: 22, 2241: 22, 2242: 22, 2243: 22, 2244: 22, 2245: 22, 2246: 22, 2247: 22, 2248: 22, 2249: 22, 2250: 22, 2251: 22, 2252: 22, 2253: 22, 2332: 23, 2333: 23, 2334: 23, 2335: 23, 2336: 23, 2337: 23, 2338: 23, 2339: 23, 2340: 23, 2341: 23, 2342: 23, 2343: 23, 2344: 23, 2345: 23, 2346: 23, 2347: 23, 2348: 23, 2349: 23, 2350: 23, 2351: 23, 2352: 23, 2353: 23, 2354: 23, 2433: 24, 2434: 24, 2435: 24, 2436: 24, 2437: 24, 2438: 24, 2439: 24, 2440: 24, 2441: 24, 2442: 24, 2443: 24, 2444: 24, 2445: 24, 2446: 24, 2447: 24, 2448: 24, 2449: 24, 2450: 24, 2451: 24, 2452: 24, 2453: 24, 2454: 24, 2455: 24, 2534: 25, 2535: 25, 2536: 25, 2537: 25, 2538: 25, 2539: 25, 2540: 25, 2541: 25, 2542: 25, 2543: 25, 2544: 25, 2545: 25, 2546: 25, 2547: 25, 2548: 25, 2549: 25, 2550: 25, 2551: 25, 2552: 25, 2553: 25, 2554: 25, 2555: 25, 2556: 25, 2635: 26, 2636: 26, 2637: 26, 2638: 26, 2639: 26, 2640: 26, 2641: 26, 2642: 26, 2643: 26, 2644: 26, 2645: 26, 2646: 26, 2647: 26, 2648: 26, 2649: 26, 2650: 26, 2651: 26, 2652: 26, 2653: 26, 2654: 26, 2655: 26, 2656: 26, 2657: 26, 2736: 27, 2737: 27, 2738: 27, 2739: 27, 2740: 27, 2741: 27, 2742: 27, 2743: 27, 2744: 27, 2745: 27, 2746: 27, 2747: 27, 2748: 27, 2749: 27, 2750: 27, 2751: 27, 2752: 27, 2753: 27, 2754: 27, 2755: 27, 2756: 27, 2757: 27, 2758: 27, 2838: 28, 2839: 28, 2840: 28, 2841: 28, 2842: 28, 2843: 28, 2844: 28, 2845: 28, 2846: 28, 2847: 28, 2848: 28, 2849: 28, 2850: 28, 2851: 28, 2852: 28, 2853: 28, 2854: 28, 2855: 28, 2856: 28, 2857: 28, 2858: 28, 2939: 29, 2940: 29, 2941: 29, 2942: 29, 2943: 29, 2944: 29, 2945: 29, 2946: 29, 2947: 29, 2948: 29, 2949: 29, 2950: 29, 2951: 29, 2952: 29, 2953: 29, 2954: 29, 2955: 29, 2956: 29, 2957: 29, 2958: 29, 2959: 29, 3041: 30, 3042: 30, 3043: 30, 3044: 30, 3045: 30, 3046: 30, 3047: 30, 3048: 30, 3049: 30, 3050: 30, 3051: 30, 3052: 30, 3053: 30, 3054: 30, 3055: 30, 3056: 30, 3057: 30, 3058: 30, 3059: 30, 3143: 31, 3144: 31, 3145: 31, 3146: 31, 3147: 31, 3148: 31, 3149: 31, 3150: 31, 3151: 31, 3152: 31, 3153: 31, 3154: 31, 3155: 31, 3156: 31, 3157: 31, 3158: 31, 3159: 31, 3245: 32, 3246: 32, 3247: 32, 3248: 32, 3249: 32, 3250: 32, 3251: 32, 3252: 32, 3253: 32, 3254: 32, 3255: 32, 3256: 32, 3257: 32, 3258: 32, 3259: 32, 3347: 33, 3348: 33, 3349: 33, 3350: 33, 3351: 33, 3352: 33, 3353: 33, 3354: 33, 3355: 33, 3356: 33, 3357: 33, 3358: 33, 3359: 33, 3449: 34, 3450: 34, 3451: 34, 3452: 34, 3453: 34, 3454: 34, 3455: 34, 3456: 34, 3457: 34, 3458: 34, 3459: 34, 3552: 35, 3553: 35, 3554: 35, 3555: 35, 3556: 35, 3557: 35, 3558: 35}, 'y': {1330: 17, 1331: 18, 1332: 19, 1333: 20, 1334: 21, 1335: 22, 1336: 23, 1429: 15, 1430: 16, 1431: 17, 1432: 18, 1433: 19, 1434: 20, 1435: 21, 1436: 22, 1437: 23, 1438: 24, 1439: 25, 1529: 14, 1530: 15, 1531: 16, 1532: 17, 1533: 18, 1534: 19, 1535: 20, 1536: 21, 1537: 22, 1538: 23, 1539: 24, 1540: 25, 1541: 26, 1629: 13, 1630: 14, 1631: 15, 1632: 16, 1633: 17, 1634: 18, 1635: 19, 1636: 20, 1637: 21, 1638: 22, 1639: 23, 1640: 24, 1641: 25, 1642: 26, 1643: 27, 1729: 12, 1730: 13, 1731: 14, 1732: 15, 1733: 16, 1734: 17, 1735: 18, 1736: 19, 1737: 20, 1738: 21, 1739: 22, 1740: 23, 1741: 24, 1742: 25, 1743: 26, 1744: 27, 1745: 28, 1829: 11, 1830: 12, 1831: 13, 1832: 14, 1833: 15, 1834: 16, 1835: 17, 1836: 18, 1837: 19, 1838: 20, 1839: 21, 1840: 22, 1841: 23, 1842: 24, 1843: 25, 1844: 26, 1845: 27, 1846: 28, 1847: 29, 1929: 10, 1930: 11, 1931: 12, 1932: 13, 1933: 14, 1934: 15, 1935: 16, 1936: 17, 1937: 18, 1938: 19, 1939: 20, 1940: 21, 1941: 22, 1942: 23, 1943: 24, 1944: 25, 1945: 26, 1946: 27, 1947: 28, 1948: 29, 1949: 30, 2030: 10, 2031: 11, 2032: 12, 2033: 13, 2034: 14, 2035: 15, 2036: 16, 2037: 17, 2038: 18, 2039: 19, 2040: 20, 2041: 21, 2042: 22, 2043: 23, 2044: 24, 2045: 25, 2046: 26, 2047: 27, 2048: 28, 2049: 29, 2050: 30, 2130: 9, 2131: 10, 2132: 11, 2133: 12, 2134: 13, 2135: 14, 2136: 15, 2137: 16, 2138: 17, 2139: 18, 2140: 19, 2141: 20, 2142: 21, 2143: 22, 2144: 23, 2145: 24, 2146: 25, 2147: 26, 2148: 27, 2149: 28, 2150: 29, 2151: 30, 2152: 31, 2231: 9, 2232: 10, 2233: 11, 2234: 12, 2235: 13, 2236: 14, 2237: 15, 2238: 16, 2239: 17, 2240: 18, 2241: 19, 2242: 20, 2243: 21, 2244: 22, 2245: 23, 2246: 24, 2247: 25, 2248: 26, 2249: 27, 2250: 28, 2251: 29, 2252: 30, 2253: 31, 2332: 9, 2333: 10, 2334: 11, 2335: 12, 2336: 13, 2337: 14, 2338: 15, 2339: 16, 2340: 17, 2341: 18, 2342: 19, 2343: 20, 2344: 21, 2345: 22, 2346: 23, 2347: 24, 2348: 25, 2349: 26, 2350: 27, 2351: 28, 2352: 29, 2353: 30, 2354: 31, 2433: 9, 2434: 10, 2435: 11, 2436: 12, 2437: 13, 2438: 14, 2439: 15, 2440: 16, 2441: 17, 2442: 18, 2443: 19, 2444: 20, 2445: 21, 2446: 22, 2447: 23, 2448: 24, 2449: 25, 2450: 26, 2451: 27, 2452: 28, 2453: 29, 2454: 30, 2455: 31, 2534: 9, 2535: 10, 2536: 11, 2537: 12, 2538: 13, 2539: 14, 2540: 15, 2541: 16, 2542: 17, 2543: 18, 2544: 19, 2545: 20, 2546: 21, 2547: 22, 2548: 23, 2549: 24, 2550: 25, 2551: 26, 2552: 27, 2553: 28, 2554: 29, 2555: 30, 2556: 31, 2635: 9, 2636: 10, 2637: 11, 2638: 12, 2639: 13, 2640: 14, 2641: 15, 2642: 16, 2643: 17, 2644: 18, 2645: 19, 2646: 20, 2647: 21, 2648: 22, 2649: 23, 2650: 24, 2651: 25, 2652: 26, 2653: 27, 2654: 28, 2655: 29, 2656: 30, 2657: 31, 2736: 9, 2737: 10, 2738: 11, 2739: 12, 2740: 13, 2741: 14, 2742: 15, 2743: 16, 2744: 17, 2745: 18, 2746: 19, 2747: 20, 2748: 21, 2749: 22, 2750: 23, 2751: 24, 2752: 25, 2753: 26, 2754: 27, 2755: 28, 2756: 29, 2757: 30, 2758: 31, 2838: 10, 2839: 11, 2840: 12, 2841: 13, 2842: 14, 2843: 15, 2844: 16, 2845: 17, 2846: 18, 2847: 19, 2848: 20, 2849: 21, 2850: 22, 2851: 23, 2852: 24, 2853: 25, 2854: 26, 2855: 27, 2856: 28, 2857: 29, 2858: 30, 2939: 10, 2940: 11, 2941: 12, 2942: 13, 2943: 14, 2944: 15, 2945: 16, 2946: 17, 2947: 18, 2948: 19, 2949: 20, 2950: 21, 2951: 22, 2952: 23, 2953: 24, 2954: 25, 2955: 26, 2956: 27, 2957: 28, 2958: 29, 2959: 30, 3041: 11, 3042: 12, 3043: 13, 3044: 14, 3045: 15, 3046: 16, 3047: 17, 3048: 18, 3049: 19, 3050: 20, 3051: 21, 3052: 22, 3053: 23, 3054: 24, 3055: 25, 3056: 26, 3057: 27, 3058: 28, 3059: 29, 3143: 12, 3144: 13, 3145: 14, 3146: 15, 3147: 16, 3148: 17, 3149: 18, 3150: 19, 3151: 20, 3152: 21, 3153: 22, 3154: 23, 3155: 24, 3156: 25, 3157: 26, 3158: 27, 3159: 28, 3245: 13, 3246: 14, 3247: 15, 3248: 16, 3249: 17, 3250: 18, 3251: 19, 3252: 20, 3253: 21, 3254: 22, 3255: 23, 3256: 24, 3257: 25, 3258: 26, 3259: 27, 3347: 14, 3348: 15, 3349: 16, 3350: 17, 3351: 18, 3352: 19, 3353: 20, 3354: 21, 3355: 22, 3356: 23, 3357: 24, 3358: 25, 3359: 26, 3449: 15, 3450: 16, 3451: 17, 3452: 18, 3453: 19, 3454: 20, 3455: 21, 3456: 22, 3457: 23, 3458: 24, 3459: 25, 3552: 17, 3553: 18, 3554: 19, 3555: 20, 3556: 21, 3557: 22, 3558: 23}, 'val': {1330: 0.125034281657218, 1331: 0.146510549278435, 1332: 0.162798225597306, 1333: 0.174141647494022, 1334: 0.175649673690869, 1335: 0.169901008313413, 1336: 0.156392033004264, 1429: 0.131842483174851, 1430: 0.168225672551844, 1431: 0.201932264222645, 1432: 0.230401100785872, 1433: 0.252078330958949, 1434: 0.263985604687325, 1435: 0.268051528143263, 1436: 0.261530095653356, 1437: 0.244930296570094, 1438: 0.22009207169948, 1439: 0.187549231922949, 1529: 0.153095858004675, 1530: 0.199874035729114, 1531: 0.244757701084213, 1532: 0.284558765396655, 1533: 0.316793180984846, 1534: 0.340149023909276, 1535: 0.354084472188351, 1536: 0.358058903246401, 1537: 0.351864695441206, 1538: 0.335968837974345, 1539: 0.310613255308736, 1540: 0.27544685078461, 1541: 0.231994323304129, 1629: 0.159500457032148, 1630: 0.215034918221241, 1631: 0.270485127617224, 1632: 0.319682689551978, 1633: 0.360816261279786, 1634: 0.393443238781268, 1635: 0.416505736846166, 1636: 0.430942477285289, 1637: 0.435877030632285, 1638: 0.43142429605058, 1639: 0.417342163593077, 1640: 0.392302515650952, 1641: 0.357488604713231, 1642: 0.312650997630604, 1643: 0.25975200484393, 1729: 0.150632212086862, 1730: 0.213978884190518, 1731: 0.276192394596032, 1732: 0.334270555672597, 1733: 0.384350227824776, 1734: 0.424885525705118, 1735: 0.457535482893584, 1736: 0.480442204985809, 1737: 0.494861699663275, 1738: 0.500878083815911, 1739: 0.497602573106659, 1740: 0.484604632022002, 1741: 0.461481033563102, 1742: 0.429373154225231, 1743: 0.386069997384315, 1744: 0.332135523694824, 1745: 0.270535104628146, 1829: 0.129998195479659, 1830: 0.194692030946869, 1831: 0.264528418749854, 1832: 0.329232553829933, 1833: 0.388080739694423, 1834: 0.437566636695414, 1835: 0.477473961526633, 1836: 0.509516941030984, 1837: 0.53231011147668, 1838: 0.546207257608824, 1839: 0.552354038693736, 1840: 0.54967660715399, 1841: 0.538706527622593, 1842: 0.517834003180138, 1843: 0.487968966600504, 1844: 0.447311753283767, 1845: 0.395006491931055, 1846: 0.332118376178183, 1847: 0.260891128021488, 1929: 0.0994279755433359, 1930: 0.162043981089431, 1931: 0.233590996957115, 1932: 0.306104409491314, 1933: 0.372593692874887, 1934: 0.430840495968894, 1935: 0.478569577606473, 1936: 0.518026915739154, 1937: 0.549251628916258, 1938: 0.570904612342847, 1939: 0.58551154195664, 1940: 0.592643868905514, 1941: 0.59096830502007, 1942: 0.580617725077176, 1943: 0.561698640366728, 1944: 0.533930838336894, 1945: 0.495168064867138, 1946: 0.445782525177784, 1947: 0.384707458850997, 1948: 0.31218764421186, 1949: 0.233635790813245, 2030: 0.119552233147502, 2031: 0.189200647791616, 2032: 0.264587499833159, 2033: 0.338158651415947, 2034: 0.40384646392135, 2035: 0.461089645607533, 2036: 0.509519342692187, 2037: 0.547722857849805, 2038: 0.57825857166853, 2039: 0.6005963669379, 2040: 0.615145696550745, 2041: 0.62137727725311, 2042: 0.621273091524599, 2043: 0.612023383755283, 2044: 0.594861468248791, 2045: 0.568718312124375, 2046: 0.532808090124623, 2047: 0.485620416485279, 2048: 0.426390086433996, 2049: 0.355805292911877, 2050: 0.275725557554215, 2130: 0.078453643565277, 2131: 0.136939698336454, 2132: 0.210195844884629, 2133: 0.287371236106773, 2134: 0.360855082747978, 2135: 0.426467519668884, 2136: 0.482304412170155, 2137: 0.530121016302499, 2138: 0.568643527175895, 2139: 0.598189464984326, 2140: 0.620306747894564, 2141: 0.634691085737181, 2142: 0.642065354531906, 2143: 0.642214519430184, 2144: 0.634075027178758, 2145: 0.618017427425247, 2146: 0.593150832427166, 2147: 0.558791443915162, 2148: 0.513611097882573, 2149: 0.457388711220084, 2150: 0.387998529856863, 2151: 0.308265619530798, 2152: 0.224768194629101, 2231: 0.0878414846284422, 2232: 0.150824317634651, 2233: 0.226169105542203, 2234: 0.303608008111944, 2235: 0.37618032782532, 2236: 0.44104971964592, 2237: 0.496350883165771, 2238: 0.5432695458109, 2239: 0.581490180204469, 2240: 0.610545512567437, 2241: 0.632658188234618, 2242: 0.647069665981663, 2243: 0.654344913435336, 2244: 0.655018720760291, 2245: 0.647610197098396, 2246: 0.63231028220327, 2247: 0.608085427087214, 2248: 0.575604891832832, 2249: 0.531635768266655, 2250: 0.47725871873977, 2251: 0.410312556932152, 2252: 0.33197022782417, 2253: 0.245805218959435, 2332: 0.0937230787419447, 2333: 0.158103193881048, 2334: 0.235211494302887, 2335: 0.312832984337454, 2336: 0.38465814655434, 2337: 0.448858532657483, 2338: 0.503338051534901, 2339: 0.549677229120918, 2340: 0.586906290410358, 2341: 0.61664592278564, 2342: 0.637769306728882, 2343: 0.652843164727909, 2344: 0.660051926515903, 2345: 0.660481926513926, 2346: 0.653883442426453, 2347: 0.638778425993686, 2348: 0.615355802194484, 2349: 0.583336213522871, 2350: 0.540507047532096, 2351: 0.486758910316598, 2352: 0.420854410192893, 2353: 0.344632347188776, 2354: 0.258160624630319, 2433: 0.0971700301621487, 2434: 0.161091671505116, 2435: 0.237729901187461, 2436: 0.314266103869342, 2437: 0.385522098280158, 2438: 0.449525696233584, 2439: 0.503235015878352, 2440: 0.548789012315138, 2441: 0.586378978535796, 2442: 0.615049762208693, 2443: 0.636921506466941, 2444: 0.651001965907661, 2445: 0.658170047988714, 2446: 0.659078500867402, 2447: 0.651563370229347, 2448: 0.636918412007088, 2449: 0.614266816685885, 2450: 0.582379130924729, 2451: 0.539773262186461, 2452: 0.487585411523152, 2453: 0.422138679998665, 2454: 0.345922232189227, 2455: 0.262222994404912, 2534: 0.0939624880013175, 2535: 0.157783728246477, 2536: 0.233125263433041, 2537: 0.309046910245403, 2538: 0.378942821429244, 2539: 0.44182082177317, 2540: 0.49584039118338, 2541: 0.540751080999447, 2542: 0.578011610132132, 2543: 0.607069155503352, 2544: 0.628819681871452, 2545: 0.643195708371906, 2546: 0.650771389750413, 2547: 0.650808014757331, 2548: 0.643378522353223, 2549: 0.628971104869408, 2550: 0.606429889816824, 2551: 0.573590302231565, 2552: 0.532148251400124, 2553: 0.479621700413826, 2554: 0.415406988243864, 2555: 0.341265139066589, 2556: 0.257499642682461, 2635: 0.0878546571924221, 2636: 0.148003602097296, 2637: 0.220866231688989, 2638: 0.295166980859872, 2639: 0.364676500404719, 2640: 0.426498398306351, 2641: 0.479662981104298, 2642: 0.525833649486667, 2643: 0.562612353567895, 2644: 0.592019729219471, 2645: 0.614089521388066, 2646: 0.628253072660444, 2647: 0.635515466017992, 2648: 0.635712813172631, 2649: 0.6284023399705, 2650: 0.613198055464572, 2651: 0.58962397483174, 2652: 0.557877849684715, 2653: 0.516156418497575, 2654: 0.463586872048478, 2655: 0.399615837249564, 2656: 0.325871994066377, 2657: 0.244597109259556, 2736: 0.0767886698220618, 2737: 0.131909525079444, 2738: 0.200701721949108, 2739: 0.272308926051485, 2740: 0.340863352425599, 2741: 0.402486439390557, 2742: 0.456356120684202, 2743: 0.501634669770108, 2744: 0.538631445061214, 2745: 0.568546615174782, 2746: 0.591523146850388, 2747: 0.605768623061726, 2748: 0.612649350862559, 2749: 0.613275096015372, 2750: 0.605165277123499, 2751: 0.590326949248391, 2752: 0.566587155507915, 2753: 0.533954120848652, 2754: 0.492314137452831, 2755: 0.439416916402075, 2756: 0.376509580480089, 2757: 0.303491614636041, 2758: 0.224745281658628, 2838: 0.11366695496859, 2839: 0.175801515268564, 2840: 0.244390203361104, 2841: 0.310572615167298, 2842: 0.371287232292331, 2843: 0.42424996978231, 2844: 0.470228266982446, 2845: 0.507602803202526, 2846: 0.537709813012752, 2847: 0.56002353958147, 2848: 0.574611454919113, 2849: 0.581782538295325, 2850: 0.581746721770724, 2851: 0.573913466142369, 2852: 0.55842005096586, 2853: 0.53453679429896, 2854: 0.501659905049031, 2855: 0.458799015712769, 2856: 0.406773800829344, 2857: 0.343950027091123, 2858: 0.272451418457149, 2939: 0.0907683242020857, 2940: 0.145595063683456, 2941: 0.207629553951152, 2942: 0.272414081399819, 2943: 0.331639330105061, 2944: 0.384333848405241, 2945: 0.429801412255365, 2946: 0.467303244356339, 2947: 0.49793515515547, 2948: 0.520546116719654, 2949: 0.535402547924623, 2950: 0.542844223421866, 2951: 0.543006763864376, 2952: 0.535046806879362, 2953: 0.519155519264988, 2954: 0.494247334574059, 2955: 0.461568128405251, 2956: 0.41841003094388, 2957: 0.366423662455871, 2958: 0.304189644904162, 2959: 0.235764889199854, 3041: 0.112972842236976, 3042: 0.167716926720786, 3043: 0.226684554190913, 3044: 0.28382704496528, 3045: 0.335105841246755, 3046: 0.381143566005808, 3047: 0.419131259378266, 3048: 0.449570643656543, 3049: 0.472593630684729, 3050: 0.48794282856237, 3051: 0.495820184090723, 3052: 0.495748722861365, 3053: 0.487818712459319, 3054: 0.471432808256945, 3055: 0.446482062404646, 3056: 0.412808327959312, 3057: 0.370321767175141, 3058: 0.31865273420607, 3059: 0.258972974853289, 3143: 0.126687774567458, 3144: 0.178230961999045, 3145: 0.230710446213052, 3146: 0.28069526025422, 3147: 0.324501501138709, 3148: 0.362263092361594, 3149: 0.393233232032102, 3150: 0.416570608660145, 3151: 0.431753625914107, 3152: 0.440016630164296, 3153: 0.440213147015875, 3154: 0.430963280769682, 3155: 0.414508898897225, 3156: 0.389206042543721, 3157: 0.355664639154251, 3158: 0.313509605055651, 3159: 0.26335579520506, 3245: 0.130266006430133, 3246: 0.175551467523299, 3247: 0.220804642818566, 3248: 0.262378659014485, 3249: 0.298969280012685, 3250: 0.329571866067572, 3251: 0.352801865689826, 3252: 0.368197838780504, 3253: 0.376423424202345, 3254: 0.376708216860075, 3255: 0.368187314378747, 3256: 0.351231014723654, 3257: 0.325244163022708, 3258: 0.291880699844488, 3259: 0.251697449001074, 3347: 0.123498224663236, 3348: 0.161163946417205, 3349: 0.197870476826703, 3350: 0.23226209334847, 3351: 0.260893935156872, 3352: 0.282845032062618, 3353: 0.298371126513732, 3354: 0.305911742267994, 3355: 0.305704747641352, 3356: 0.297421065057385, 3357: 0.279794191911042, 3358: 0.254895731317717, 3359: 0.223656730596717, 3449: 0.106299197949988, 3450: 0.13582921788929, 3451: 0.163842506355784, 3452: 0.189298013220722, 3453: 0.210140031451773, 3454: 0.223974696889605, 3455: 0.231308229605224, 3456: 0.230481723005608, 3457: 0.222150133716654, 3458: 0.205803612908876, 3459: 0.183174205821337, 3552: 0.10469301447903, 3553: 0.12441248186846, 3554: 0.140223908851793, 3555: 0.15196366533768, 3556: 0.157504487224286, 3557: 0.156930642384745, 3558: 0.150006239662724}} )
dfp=df_a.pivot("x","y","val")        
sns.heatmap(dfp,center=0,square=True)

x_center=(0.5*(max(df_a['x'])+min(df_a['x'])))
y_center=(0.5*(max(df_a['y'])+min(df_a['y'])))
radius=10
```